# Срок действия сертификата уже истек

Tags: apache, ssl, cloudflare, certificate

Есть вебприложение, сертификат на нем висит от `cloudflare`, вебсервер `apache`. У меня все нормально

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А у клиента

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообще ума не приложу где смотреть, как дебажить или фиксить. У него как будто истекший, а у меня действительный, хотя заходим на одну и ту же страницу

Comment: Слишком много неизвестных. Из очевидных: 1) Корректно ли время на стороне клиент. 2) По скриншоту, похоже на вин 7? тогда, стоят ли KB3020369 и KB3125574. Дело в том, что DST Root CA X3 был просрочен 30го сентября. В систему нужно установить новый сертификат или ручками в локальную машину или с помощью вышестоящих обновлений

Comment: @PZBird Установка нового сертификата клиенту помогла, можете оформить в качестве ответа?

Comment: Клиент должен был своевременно устанавливать обновления Windows 7 (а лучше вообще переходить на Windows 10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

30-го сентября 2021 года, у корневого сертификата `DST Root CA X3` закончился срок действия. В связи с этим, часть клиентов получили проблемы с доступам к сайтам, подписанными сертификатами, выданными этим CA.

Для решения проблемы на Windows 7 нужно поставить обновления KB3020369 и KB3125574.

Альтернативным путем решения (ручным), необходимо:

Шаг 1: Запустить Run (выполнить)

Шаг 2: Запустить `certmgr.msc`.

Шаг 3: В менеджере сертификатов выбрать `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`  > `Certificates`. (Доверенные корневые центры сертификации > Сертификаты)

Шаг 4: Найти устаревший `DST Root CA X3` и удалить его.

Шаг 5: Скачать новый [корневой сертификат](https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.der)

Шаг 6: Установить сертификат в `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` (Доверенные корневые центры сертификации)

Шаг 7: Если открыт браузер - перезапустить его

Шаг 8: Наслаждаться чистым интернетом с https